# How to exit chocolatey installation if a condition is not met?

Tags: windows, powershell, chocolatey

In my usual `PowerShell` scripts, as usual, I use `Exit 1` to exit the scripts while I am doing normal sanity checking, so if a condition is not met, I exit early and notify the user to fulfill the condition.

Is `Chocolatey` package development following the same PoSh way? Or is there any `Chocolatey` way, such as `helpers` or `core-extension` that does this for the developers? for example:

I want the user to provide `SQL Server iso` path for my `SQL Server` chocolatey package `--params "/IsoPath:C:\Pkg"`, if no path is provided the package installation should fail:

```
$pp = Get-PackageParameters
if (!pp['IsoPath']) {
   Write-Host "No 'ISO' path is provided, please provide path in '--params'"
   Exit 1
}
```

Does the above snippet work to fail the installation or is there any chocolatey way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways that you can do this.

The first would be to simply throw an exception.  A good example of that is in the [vcredist140](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-coreteampackages/blob/master/automatic/vcredist140/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1#L12-L33) package, where it decides on whether this package is intended to be used on the OS it is currently being installed on.

```
$os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$version = [Version]$os.Version
if ($version -ge [Version]'6.1' -and $version -lt [Version]'6.2' -and 
$os.ServicePackMajorVersion -lt 1)
{
  # On Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2, Service Pack 1 is required.
  throw 'This package requires Service Pack 1 to be installed first. The 
"KB976932" package may be used to install it.'
}
elseif ($version -ge [Version]'6.0' -and $version -lt [Version]'6.1' -and 
$os.ServicePackMajorVersion -lt 2)
{
  # On Windows Vista / Server 2008, Service Pack 2 is required.
  throw 'This package requires Service Pack 2 to be installed first.'
}
elseif ($version -ge [Version]'5.2' -and $version -lt [Version]'6.0' -and 
$os.ServicePackMajorVersion -lt 2)
{
  # On Windows Server 2003 / XP x64, Service Pack 2 is required.
  throw 'This package requires Service Pack 2 to be installed first.'
}
elseif ($version -ge [Version]'5.1' -and $version -lt [Version]'5.2' -and 
$os.ServicePackMajorVersion -lt 3)
{
  # On Windows XP, Service Pack 3 is required.
  throw 'This package requires Service Pack 3 to be installed first.'
}
```

An alternative method would be to use the `Set-PowerShellExitCode` helper method which Chocolatey provides:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-set-power-shell-exit-code

If you need to specifically set the exit code to something that you use later.

Comment: Thanks Gary, `Set-PowerShellExitCode` was something I was looking for.